# UDP Discovery Code Unable to Receive UDP Broadcast

Tags: networking, udp, endpoint, udpclient

I need to write a mobile app (Xamarin) to send a UDP broadcast, then have a desktop app (WPF/WinForms) listen to the UDP broadcast. I got the sample from the link below, but it is not working. The Xamarin app seems okay, but the desktop app never gets past the "listener.Receive(ref ...)" statement. I would appreciate help. Thanks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-udp-services

Xamarin Server:

```
    private void StartUdpDiscovery()
    {
        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        IPAddress broadcast = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255");

        //byte[] sendbuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(args[0]);
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(broadcast, 11000);

        byte[] data = new byte[2]; //broadcast data
        data[0] = 0x0A;
        data[1] = 0x60;
        s.SendTo(data, ep);

        Console.WriteLine("Message sent to the broadcast address");
    }
```

Desktop Client/Listener:

```
    private void StartUdpListener()
    {
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        //IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255"), listenPort);

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast");
                byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP); // NOTE: THE DEBUGGER STALLS HERE AND NEVER MOVES ON...

                Console.WriteLine($"Received broadcast from {groupEP} :");
                Console.WriteLine($" {Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)}");
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            listener.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the IP address was incorrect.

```
    IPAddress broadcast = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255");
```